# Multicriteria sorting object keys using Javascript and loadash

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, lodash, array-multisort

I am trying to sort an object by key using multiple criteria, Javascript, and [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). I don't have to use Lodash, but thought that would be easier. I am open to whatever will work at this point. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!! Thank you in advance.

Here is an example object I am working with:

```js
var object = {
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_filter": "some value",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295945589000200_filter": "asdf",
  "149098531921500909_source": "js.content_ids",
  "149098531921500909_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295944269000199_settovar": "",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_source": "js.content_type",
  "148295945589000200_filtertype": "defined",
  "148295945589000200_source": "js.content_type",
  "148295944269000199_settotext": "adsf",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_filter": "some value",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_filtertype": "some_value",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_filter": "some value",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295944269000199_setoption": "text",
  "148295944269000199_set": "js.content_name",
  "149099546962400202_source": "js.acme_id",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_source": "js.acme_page",
  "149099546962400202_filter": "",
  "149098531921500909_filter": "some value",
  "149099546962400202_filtertype": "defined",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_source": "js.content_name"
}
```

This is what I am trying to do:

Sort the object based on the first 18 numbers in each key. If there is only one block of numbers, list that first, then list the keys with a second block of numbers in the series and in order. Then, sort by the remaining alphabetical portion of the key.

Expected output:

```js
var object = {
  "148295944269000199_set": "js.content_name",
  "148295944269000199_setoption": "text",
  "148295944269000199_settotext": "adsf",
  "148295944269000199_settovar": "",
  "148295945589000200_filter": "asdf",
  "148295945589000200_filtertype": "defined",
  "148295945589000200_source": "js.content_type",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_filter": "some value",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_source": "js.content_type",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_filter": "some text",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_source": "js.content_name"
  "149098531921500909_filter": "some value",
  "149098531921500909_filtertype": "contains_ignore_case",
  "149098531921500909_source": "js.content_ids",
  "149099546962400202_filter": "",
  "149099546962400202_filtertype": "defined",
  "149099546962400202_source": "js.acme_page",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_filter": "some value",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_filtertype": "some_value",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_source": "js.acme_id"
}
```

Here are some of the things I have tried:

(1) Tried to add to an array and sort

```js
var array = Object.keys(object).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
})

var newObject = {};
array.forEach(function(key) {
  newObject[key] = object[key];
});
JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
```

(2) Tried removing underscores to sort

```js
var newObject = {};
Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
  newKey = key.replace(/_/g, "");
  newObject[newKey] = object[key];
});

var array = Object.keys(newObject).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
})

var newestObject = {};
array.forEach(function(key) {
  newestObject[key] = newObject[key];
});
JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
```

(3) Tried to convert to multidimensional array using lodash (called with "_") and use multi criteria sorting - I think I am the closest with this one, maybe. This requires lodash to work -https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.17.4/dist/lodash.core.js

```js
var sortable = _.toPairs(object);
var array = sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
  // check if b[0].substring(19,37) is a number first?
  if (a[0].substring(0, 18) === b[0].substring(0, 18)) {
    var x = a[1].substring(0, 18),
      y = b[1].substring(0, 18);
    return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return a[0].substring(0, 18) - b[0].substring(0, 18);
});
var output = _.fromPairs(array);
JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);
```

Comment: what is the sort order any specifications? you messed the code :(

Comment: Hi Aravind, thanks for responding. The code snippets look good on my end but maybe they didn't render properly. Here is the criteria I am looking for: Sort the object based on the first 18 numbers in each key. If there is only one block of numbers, list that first, then list the keys with a second block of numbers in the series and in order. Then, sort by the remaining alphabetical portion of the key.

Comment: sorting an object or sorting an array?? you  sample contains only an object

Comment: Sorting an object. Some of the things I tried involved converting the object to an array format, but the objective is to sort an object.

Comment: does the service returns the set of data or changes the key everytime?

Comment: the keys for the particular object will not change once created (returned)

Comment: does it changes for every service call? or stable all time and properties might be empty at sometimes? Also what is the reason for sorting an object?

Comment: The keys change for each service call (each different object) but they will stay the same for a particular object. Does that make sense? The reason for sorting is I have to add new key/value pairs with the same numbering system that have to be in a certain position in relation to the other keys.

Comment: One simple solution will be handle them in 3 different objects for each property (group) both in service and in typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this by:

1. Converting the object into a collection of key-value pairs using [`lodash#toPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toPairs).
2. Sort the collection by key using [`lodash#sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy):

   - split the key string by a `'_'` delimiter and get it's `length`.
   - replace the first occurrence of `'_'` character in the key string with the `length` of the split.
3. Use [`lodash#fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#fromPairs) to convert the sorted collection into an object.

---

```
var result = _(object)
  .toPairs()
  .sortBy(function(pair) {
    return pair[0].replace(/_/, pair[0].split('_').length);
  })
  .fromPairs()
  .value();
```

```js
var object = {
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_filter": "some value",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295945589000200_filter": "asdf",
  "149098531921500909_source": "js.content_ids",
  "149098531921500909_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295944269000199_settovar": "",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_source": "js.content_type",
  "148295945589000200_filtertype": "defined",
  "148295945589000200_source": "js.content_type",
  "148295944269000199_settotext": "adsf",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_filter": "some value",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_filtertype": "some_value",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_filter": "some value",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295944269000199_setoption": "text",
  "148295944269000199_set": "js.content_name",
  "149099546962400202_source": "js.acme_id",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_source": "js.acme_page",
  "149099546962400202_filter": "",
  "149098531921500909_filter": "some value",
  "149099546962400202_filtertype": "defined",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_source": "js.content_name"
};

var result = _(object)
  .toPairs()
  .sortBy(function(pair) {
    return pair[0].replace(/_/, pair[0].split('_').length);
  })
  .fromPairs()
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can solve this without using lodash:

```
function getKey(key) {
  return key.replace(/_/, key.split('_').length);
}

var result = Object.keys(object)
  .sort(function(k1, k2) {
    return getKey(k1).localeCompare(getKey(k2));
  })
  .reduce(function(acc, key) {
    acc[key] = object[key];
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

```js
var object = {
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_filter": "some value",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295945589000200_filter": "asdf",
  "149098531921500909_source": "js.content_ids",
  "149098531921500909_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295944269000199_settovar": "",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_source": "js.content_type",
  "148295945589000200_filtertype": "defined",
  "148295945589000200_source": "js.content_type",
  "148295944269000199_settotext": "adsf",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_filter": "some value",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_filtertype": "some_value",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_filter": "some value",
  "148295945589000200_149098530604100908_filtertype": "some_value",
  "148295944269000199_setoption": "text",
  "148295944269000199_set": "js.content_name",
  "149099546962400202_source": "js.acme_id",
  "149099546962400202_149099548423700203_source": "js.acme_page",
  "149099546962400202_filter": "",
  "149098531921500909_filter": "some value",
  "149099546962400202_filtertype": "defined",
  "148295945589000200_149099156236000910_source": "js.content_name"
};

function getKey(key) {
  return key.replace(/_/, key.split('_').length);
}

var result = Object.keys(object)
  .sort(function(k1, k2) {
    return getKey(k1).localeCompare(getKey(k2));
  })
  .reduce(function(acc, key) {
    acc[key] = object[key];
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```